# Neo4j bulk import “neo4j-admin import” OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space and OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: memory, neo4j, garbage-collection, jvm

My single machine available resource is :

```
Total machine memory: 2.00 TB
Free machine memory: 1.81 TB
Max heap memory : 910.50 MB
Processors: 192
Configured max memory: 1.63 TB
```

My file1.csv file size is 600GB

Number of entries in my csv file = 3 000 000 000

Header structure

```
attempt1 
item_col1:ID(label),item_col2,item_col3:IGNORE,item_col4:IGNORE,item_col5,item_col6,item_col7,item_col8:IGNORE
Attempt2
item_col1:ID,item_col2,item_col3:IGNORE,item_col4:IGNORE,item_col5,item_col6,item_col7,item_col8:IGNORE
Attempt3
item_col1:ID,item_col2,item_col3:IGNORE,item_col4:IGNORE,item_col5:LABEL,item_col6,item_col7,item_col8:IGNORE`
```

Neo4j version: 3.2.1

Tried with Configuration combination 1

```
 cat ../conf/neo4j.conf | grep "memory"
 dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=16000m
 dbms.memory.heap.max_size=16000m
 dbms.memory.pagecache.size=40g
```

Tried with Configuration combination 2

```
cat ../conf/neo4j.conf | grep "memory"
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=900m
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=900m
dbms.memory.pagecache.size=4g
```

Tried with Configuration combination 3

```
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=1000m
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=1000m
dbms.memory.pagecache.size=1g
```

Tried with Configuration combination 4

```
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=10g
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=10g 
dbms.memory.pagecache.size=10g
```

Tried with Configuration combination 5 ( commented) (no output)

```
   # dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=10g
   # dbms.memory.heap.max_size=10g 
   # dbms.memory.pagecache.size=10g
```

Commands tried

```
kaushik@machine1:/neo4j/import$ cl
kaushik@machine1:/neo4j/import$ rm -r ../data/databases/
kaushik@machine1:/neo4j/import$ mkdir ../data/databases/
kaushik@machine1:/neo4j/import$ cat ../conf/neo4j.conf | grep active
dbms.active_database=graph.db


kaushik@machine1:/neo4j/import$ ../bin/neo4j-admin import --mode csv --    database social.db --nodes head.csv,file1.csv
Neo4j version: 3.2.1
Importing the contents of these files into /neo4j/data/databases/social.db:
Nodes:
  /neo4j/import/head.csv
  /neo4j/import/file1.csv



Available resources:
Total machine memory: 2.00 TB
Free machine memory: 1.79 TB
Max heap memory : 910.50 MB
Processors: 192
Configured max memory: 1.61 TB
```

Error 1

```
Nodes, started 2017-07-14 05:32:51.736+0000
[*NODE:7.63 MB---------------------------------------------------|PROPERTIE|LABEL SCAN--------]    0 ?    0
Done in 40s 439ms
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at org.neo4j.csv.reader.Extractors$StringArrayExtractor.extract0(Extractors.java:739)
at org.neo4j.csv.reader.Extractors$ArrayExtractor.extract(Extractors.java:680)
at org.neo4j.csv.reader.BufferedCharSeeker.tryExtract(BufferedCharSeeker.java:239)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.InputEntityDeserializer.deserializeNextFromSource(InputEntityDeserializer.java:138)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.InputEntityDeserializer.fetchNextOrNull(InputEntityDeserializer.java:77)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.InputEntityDeserializer.fetchNextOrNull(InputEntityDeserializer.java:41)
at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.peek(PrefetchingIterator.java:60)
at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.hasNext(PrefetchingIterator.java:46)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.ParallelInputEntityDeserializer.lambda$new$0(ParallelInputEntityDeserializer.java:106)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.ParallelInputEntityDeserializer$$Lambda$150/1372918763.apply(Unknown Source)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport
```

Error 2

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at org.neo4j.csv.reader.Extractors$StringArrayExtractor.extract0(Extractors.java:739)
at org.neo4j.csv.reader.Extractors$ArrayExtractor.extract(Extractors.java:680)
at org.neo4j.csv.reader.BufferedCharSeeker.tryExtract(BufferedCharSeeker.java:239)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.InputEntityDeserializer.deserializeNextFromSource(InputEntityDeserializer.java:138)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.InputEntityDeserializer.fetchNextOrNull(InputEntityDeserializer.java:77)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.InputEntityDeserializer.fetchNextOrNull(InputEntityDeserializer.java:41)
at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.peek(PrefetchingIterator.java:60)
at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.hasNext(PrefetchingIterator.java:46)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.ParallelInputEntityDeserializer.lambda$new$0(ParallelInputEntityDeserializer.java:106)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.ParallelInputEntityDeserializer$$Lambda$150/1372918763.apply(Unknown Source)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.TicketedProcessing.lambda$submit$0(TicketedProcessing.java:110)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.TicketedProcessing$$Lambda$154/1949503798.run(Unknown Source)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.executor.DynamicTaskExecutor$Processor.run(DynamicTaskExecutor.java:237)
```

Error 3

```
Nodes, started 2017-07-14 05:39:48.602+0000
[NODE:7.63 MB-----------------------------------------------|PROPER|*LABEL SCAN---------------]    0 ?    0
Done in 42s 140ms
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3664)
at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:207)
at org.neo4j.csv.reader.Extractors$StringExtractor.extract0(Extractors.java:328)
at org.neo4j.csv.reader.Extractors$AbstractSingleValueExtractor.extract(Extractors.java:287)
at org.neo4j.csv.reader.BufferedCharSeeker.tryExtract(BufferedCharSeeker.java:239)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.InputEntityDeserializer.deserializeNextFromSource(InputEntityDeserializer.java:138)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.InputEntityDeserializer.fetchNextOrNull(InputEntityDeserializer.java:77)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.InputEntityDeserializer.fetchNextOrNull(InputEntityDeserializer.java:41)
at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.peek(PrefetchingIterator.java:60)
at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.hasNext(PrefetchingIterator.java:46)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.ParallelInputEntityDeserializer.lambda$new$0(ParallelInputEntityDeserializer.java:106)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.ParallelInputEntityDeserializer$$Lambda$150/310855317.apply(Unknown Source)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.TicketedProcessing.lambda$submit$0(TicketedProcessing.java:110)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.TicketedProcessing$$Lambda$154/679112060.run(Unknown Source)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.executor.DynamicTaskExecutor$Processor.run(DynamicTaskExecutor.java:237)
```

Error 4

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at org.neo4j.csv.reader.Extractors$StringExtractor.extract0(Extractors.java:328)
at org.neo4j.csv.reader.Extractors$AbstractSingleValueExtractor.extract(Extractors.java:287)
at org.neo4j.csv.reader.BufferedCharSeeker.tryExtract(BufferedCharSeeker.java:239)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.InputEntityDeserializer.deserializeNextFromSource(InputEntityDeserializer.java:138)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.InputEntityDeserializer.fetchNextOrNull(InputEntityDeserializer.java:77)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.InputEntityDeserializer.fetchNextOrNull(InputEntityDeserializer.java:41)
at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.peek(PrefetchingIterator.java:60)
at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.hasNext(PrefetchingIterator.java:46)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.ParallelInputEntityDeserializer.lambda$new$0(ParallelInputEntityDeserializer.java:106)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.ParallelInputEntityDeserializer$$Lambda$118/69048864.apply(Unknown Source)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.TicketedProcessing.lambda$submit$0(TicketedProcessing.java:110)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.TicketedProcessing$$Lambda$122/951451297.run(Unknown Source)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.executor.DynamicTaskExecutor$Processor.run(DynamicTaskExecutor.java:237)
```

Error 5

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3664)
at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:207)
at org.neo4j.csv.reader.Extractors$StringExtractor.extract0(Extractors.java:328)
at org.neo4j.csv.reader.Extractors$AbstractSingleValueExtractor.extract(Extractors.java:287)
at org.neo4j.csv.reader.BufferedCharSeeker.tryExtract(BufferedCharSeeker.java:239)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.InputEntityDeserializer.deserializeNextFromSource(InputEntityDeserializer.java:138)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.InputEntityDeserializer.fetchNextOrNull(InputEntityDeserializer.java:77)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.InputEntityDeserializer.fetchNextOrNull(InputEntityDeserializer.java:41)
at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.peek(PrefetchingIterator.java:60)
at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.hasNext(PrefetchingIterator.java:46)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.ParallelInputEntityDeserializer.lambda$new$0(ParallelInputEntityDeserializer.java:106)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.ParallelInputEntityDeserializer$$Lambda$118/950986004.apply(Unknown Source)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.TicketedProcessing.lambda$submit$0(TicketedProcessing.java:110)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.TicketedProcessing$$Lambda$122/151277029.run(Unknown Source)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.executor.DynamicTaskExecutor$Processor.run(DynamicTaskExecutor.java:237)
```

In general if you could explain the Chapter 9. Performance 9.1. Memory tuning with an example, it will be helpful for lot of beginners.
    https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/performance/

could you give an example to calculate dbms.memory.heap.initial_size, dbms.memory.heap.max_size, dbms.memory.pagecache.size for a sample data set of 500 GB with 3Billion entries having 10 columns of equal size in 1TB RAM machine and 100 processors.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the calculation is pretty simple if you're only doing nodes :

```
3 * 10^9 * 20 / 1024^3
```

So I would go with a heap size of at least 55Gb.
Can you try that ?

Regards,
Tom

Comment: P.S. That's for the load. I didn't say you will need that for the actual operational running of the database :-)

Comment: With dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=55g and dbms.memory.heap.max_size=55g, the command stops at 

Nodes, started 2017-07-14 17:21:20.940+0000
[*>:??-------------------- [*NODE:7.63 MB-----------  [*NODE:7.63 MB------------ ----[NODE:7.63 MB------- --[N|*PROPERTIES---- ----]    0 ∆    0
Done in 5m 41s 141ms

It's stuck at this stage. I don't see the number of nodes imported nor the data/databases getting filled up.
Any idea about dbms.memory.pagecache.size that I should set?