# neo4j-admin import : Import error: Unable to open store file: ../data/databases/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db.index

Tags: java, neo4j, jvm

I tried to execute the following command:

```
$ ../bin/neo4j-admin import --mode csv --    database graph.db --nodes head.csv,file1.csv
```

But I got this error:

```
    Import error: Unable to open store file: ../data/databases/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db.index
    Caused by:Unable to open store file: ../data/databases/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db.index
    org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.UnderlyingStorageException: Unable to open store file: ../data/databases/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db.index
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.CommonAbstractStore.checkAndLoadStorage(CommonAbstractStore.java:209)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.CommonAbstractStore.initialise(CommonAbstractStore.java:133)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.initialize(NeoStores.java:262)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.createPropertyKeyTokenStore(NeoStores.java:553)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreType$4.open(StoreType.java:65)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreType$4.open(StoreType.java:60)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.openStore(NeoStores.java:255)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.getOrCreateStore(NeoStores.java:300)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.<init>(NeoStores.java:144)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreFactory.openNeoStores(StoreFactory.java:169)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreFactory.openAllNeoStores(StoreFactory.java:133)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.store.BatchingNeoStores.<init>(BatchingNeoStores.java:118)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.store.BatchingNeoStores.batchingNeoStores(BatchingNeoStores.java:189)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.ParallelBatchImporter.getBatchingNeoStores(ParallelBatchImporter.java:272)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.ParallelBatchImporter.doImport(ParallelBatchImporter.java:167)
        at org.neo4j.tooling.ImportTool.doImport(ImportTool.java:510)
        at org.neo4j.tooling.ImportTool.main(ImportTool.java:443)
        at org.neo4j.tooling.ImportTool.main(ImportTool.java:354)
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/data3/kaushik2/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db.index (Too many open files)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:333)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:257)
        at org.neo4j.io.fs.DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.open(DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.java:68)
        at org.neo4j.io.fs.DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.open(DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.java:53)
        at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.SingleFilePageSwapper.<init>(SingleFilePageSwapper.java:152)
        at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.SingleFilePageSwapperFactory.createPageSwapper(SingleFilePageSwapperFactory.java:71)
        at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPagedFile.<init>(MuninnPagedFile.java:135)
        at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPageCache.map(MuninnPageCache.java:362)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.CommonAbstractStore.checkAndLoadStorage(CommonAbstractStore.java:182)
        ... 17 more
```

The parameter and configurations used for this command [are here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45097469/neo4j-bulk-import-neo4j-admin-import-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-and-out). What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

You're facing a **Too many open files** problem.

```
ulimit -a
```

will show the current limit and either a particular process is taking up too many (check that with lsof for example) and you'll have to kick that process or you'll have to raise the limit (the how depends on your os but there's many many many procedures floating around, you should have no trouble finding one).

Hope this helps,
Tom